# Initializing SurfaceView with a Drawable

Tags: android, drawable, surfaceview

I'd like to open up a `SurfaceView` with a icon placed in the center of the screen when an application is first started.  I'm evoking icon creation using an implementation of `SurfaceHolder.Callback` to track when the 'Canvas' object is ready.  My question is is there a better way?  Are there less cumbersome methods of starting a `SurfaceView` with some `Drawables` loaded on creation without having to resort to placing draw logic within a callback object?

Here's my code for reference.  First the object which does drawing:

```
public class CanvasDraw{
    protected final SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    protected final Drawable mDrawable;

    public interface DrawLogic{
        void draw(Rect _surface);
    }

    public CanvasDraw(SurfaceView _view, Drawable _drawable){
        mHolder = _view.getHolder();
        mDrawable = _drawable;
    }

    public void draw(DrawLogic _logic){
        Canvas canvas = null;
        try{
            canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas();
            if( canvas != null ){
                Log.i("DRAWABLE", "Drawing " + mDrawable.toString());
                _logic.draw( mHolder.getSurfaceFrame() );
                mDrawable.draw(canvas);
            }
            else{
                Log.i("DRAWABLE", "Canvas null valued");
            }
        }
        finally{
            if( canvas != null ){
                mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then my private callback object:

```
private class DrawOnceCallback implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private final SurfaceHolder mHolder;

    public DrawOnceCallback(SurfaceHolder _holder ){
        mHolder = _holder;
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i("SURFACEHOLDER","Surface created.  Canvas available.");
        mDrawTiles.draw( new CanvasDraw.DrawLogic(){

            @Override
            public void draw(Rect _surface) {
                mTiles.setBounds( 
                    _surface.centerX() - mDrawWidth/2,
                    _surface.centerY() - mDrawHeight/2,
                    _surface.centerX() + mDrawHeight/2,
                    _surface.centerY() + mDrawHeight/2);
            }

        });
        mHolder.removeCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {Log.i("SURFACEHOLDER","Surface destroyed.");}
}
```

Comment: I am having lots of trouble using SurfaceView. I can not finish SurfaceView like activity have finish() mehtod. I am getting OutOfMemoryException when I open say 13 SufraceView ...ooohh I am in trouble. do you know how to finish them? I am extending my class with SurfaceView.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this simply by assigning the image I wanted to a view in the layout XML file. If you've got to wait until your canvas and all that is ready anyways why not just use a default property?  My opening splash screen was just a view with

```
android:background="@drawable/splash"
```

added to its layout.